# App Engine + Webmaster Tools

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've been trying for a while now to get my Python App Engine app onto the Chrome Web Store, however, when I try to upload, Google tells me I need to confirm that its my domain (I'm on an appspot.com domain). I have tried the first 3 methods (meta tag, file, and analytics) in several different ways but they haven't worked. Is there any way around this? Or, rather, how can I verify an App Engine domain?

Comment: Try showing us what exactly you did for at least one method so maybe we can see your error

Comment: Go to http://book-tracker.appspot.com to see the code for the analytics method and the meta method. Webmaster tools refuses to detect either.

Comment: I'm not sure what info if any is encoded in that "content" attribute but you might want to delete that comment just to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I go to http://book-tracker.appspot.com/ it asks me for my Google Account.

Try disabling login required before trying activation.